# How to create own snmp simulator using snmp4j agent?

Tags: java, snmp

As per title, I want to create a snmp device agent simulator. Now, in my hand, I have a text file containing a bunch of oids and its value (via snmp walk).

I would like to add all this into the simulator as statics oids. I did create one simple function to test whether it register this oid (I think its correct). But so far, I can't get the result that I've wanted.

I copy and paste the TestAgent code.

public class AgentUtil extends BaseAgent {

```
static {
    LogFactory.setLogFactory(new Log4jLogFactory());
}

private String address;
public static boolean STOP=false;
private Hashtable oid_values = new Hashtable();

public AgentUtil(String address,Hashtable oid_values) throws IOException {

    super(new File("conf.agent"), new File("bootCounter.agent"),
            new CommandProcessor(new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID())));
    this.address = address;
    this.oid_values = oid_values;
    agent.setWorkerPool(ThreadPool.create("RequestPool", 4));        
}    

@Override
protected void registerManagedObjects() {

}

public void registerManagedObject(ManagedObject mo) {
    try {
        server.register(mo, null);

    } catch (DuplicateRegistrationException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}


public void registerCustomMO() {

//        String key = "";

        try {    
//                Iterator iterator = oid_values.keySet().iterator();
//                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
//                    key = (String) iterator.next();    
                server.register(createManagedObject(),null);                    
//                }    

        } catch (DuplicateRegistrationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
}

private ManagedObject createManagedObject() {


    VariableBinding vb = new VariableBinding(new OID("0"),new OctetString("WinsXP"));
    StaticMOGroup group = new StaticMOGroup(new OID("1.2.3.4.5.6.7"),new     VariableBinding[]{vb});
    return group;
}

public void unregisterManagedObject(MOGroup moGroup) {
    moGroup.unregisterMOs(server, getContext(moGroup));
}

/*
 * Empty implementation
 */
@Override
protected void addNotificationTargets(SnmpTargetMIB targetMIB,
        SnmpNotificationMIB notificationMIB) {

       targetMIB.addDefaultTDomains();
}

/**
 * Minimal View based Access Control
 * 
 * http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2575.html
 */
@Override
protected void addViews(VacmMIB vacm) {

    vacm.addGroup(SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPv2c, new OctetString(
            "cpublic"), new OctetString("v1v2group"),
            StorageType.nonVolatile);

    vacm.addAccess(new OctetString("v1v2group"), new OctetString("public"),
            SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_ANY, SecurityLevel.NOAUTH_NOPRIV,
            MutableVACM.VACM_MATCH_EXACT, new OctetString("fullReadView"),
            new OctetString("fullWriteView"), new OctetString(
                    "fullNotifyView"), StorageType.nonVolatile);

    vacm.addViewTreeFamily(new OctetString("fullReadView"), new OID("1.3"),
            new OctetString(), VacmMIB.vacmViewIncluded,
            StorageType.nonVolatile);
}

/**
 * User based Security Model, only applicable to
 * SNMP v.3
 * 
 */
protected void addUsmUser(USM usm) {
}

protected void initTransportMappings() throws IOException {
    transportMappings = new TransportMapping[1];
    Address addr = GenericAddress.parse(address);
    TransportMapping tm = TransportMappings.getInstance()
            .createTransportMapping(addr);
    transportMappings[0] = tm;
}    

/**
 * Start method invokes some initialization methods needed to
 * start the agent
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void start() throws IOException {

    init();
    loadConfig(ImportModes.REPLACE_CREATE); 
    addShutdownHook();
    getServer().addContext(new OctetString("public"));
    finishInit();
    registerCustomMO();        
    run();
    sendColdStartNotification();

}


protected void unregisterManagedObjects() {
    // here we should unregister those objects previously registered...
}

/**
 * The table of community strings configured in the SNMP
 * engine's Local Configuration Datastore (LCD).
 * 
 * We only configure one, "public".
 */
protected void addCommunities(SnmpCommunityMIB communityMIB) {
    Variable[] com2sec = new Variable[] { 
            new OctetString("public"), // community name
            new OctetString("cpublic"), // security name
            getAgent().getContextEngineID(), // local engine ID
            new OctetString("public"), // default context name
            new OctetString(), // transport tag
            new Integer32(StorageType.nonVolatile), // storage type
            new Integer32(RowStatus.active) // row status
    };
    MOTableRow row = communityMIB.getSnmpCommunityEntry().createRow(
            new OctetString("public2public").toSubIndex(true), com2sec);
    communityMIB.getSnmpCommunityEntry().addRow(row);
}

public void runAgent() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    while(!STOP) {
        System.out.println("Agent running...");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}    

}
```

Here's my snmp tester print outs

> [Client] Target address : udp:127.0.0.1/162 [Client] Send PDU :
>   GET[requestID=1075357385, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0,
>   VBS[1.2.3.4.5.6.7 = Null]] [Client] RESPONSE from 127.0.0.1/162 :
>   noSuchObject

Here's some printout on the agent side

> WARN : org.snmp4j.agent.io.MOServerPersistence - Context 'public' is
>   no longer supported by agent INFO : org.snmp4j.agent.DefaultMOServer -
>   Registered MO StaticMOGroup[root=1.2.3.4.5.6.7,vbs={}] in default
>   context with scope
>   org.snmp4j.agent.DefaultMOScope[lowerBound=1.2.3.4.5.6.7,lowerIncluded=true,upperBound=1.2.3.4.5.6.8,upperIncluded=false] INFO : org.snmp4j.agent.mo.snmp.NotificationOriginatorImpl -
>   Notification 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1 reported with [] for context
>   Agent running... 
>   Agent running... 
>   Agent running... 
>   Agent running... 
>   Agent running... 
>   Agent running...

Am I doing it correctly? Oh, btw, I'm using snmp4j-Agent library. Let me know if you need additional info.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: In a more recent example it says that the line "loadConfig(ImportModes.REPLACE_CREATE);" is the source of problems and it is commented out ...

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, there's a pythonic tool with a very similar functionality:

http://snmpsim.sf.net